# Java: Simple BigDecimal logical error

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've got a simple piece of code that isn't behaving as it should.

This piece of code is attempting to add an array of BigDecimals to then divide by array.length to find an average. However, the first phase of the algorithm fails to add the arrays together correctly (in the variable "sum").

```
public BigDecimal getAverageHeight()
{
    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);
    BigDecimal[] heights = getAllHeights();

    for (int a = 0; a < heights.length; a++)
    {
        sum.add(heights[a]);
        System.out.println("Height[" + a + "] = " + heights[a]);
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }        

    return sum.divide(new BigDecimal(heights.length));
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Height[0] = 24  
Sum = 0.00  
Height[1] = 24  
Sum = 0.00  
Height[2] = 24  
Sum = 0.00  
Height[3] = 26  
Sum = 0.00  
Height[4] = 26  
Sum = 0.00  
Height[5] = 26  
Sum = 0.00
```

I'm sure its a simple error, but I'm getting tired of starring at the problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference, your problem is solved by reading the Javadoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`BigDecial.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) *returns* the sum, it does *not* alter it. Do this:

```
sum = sum.add(heights[a]);
```

Comment: The ole immutable value class problem... Yup, it's a trap for new players, and we programmers are all new players... constantly to start with, and occasionally as we gain experience. Sigh.

Answer (score 4):

[BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) object are immutable, all its methods modifying its value return a new `BigDecimal` object. The newly created object contains the value modified.

You need to do something like this:

```
sum = sum.add(heights[a]);
```

This also goes for the `setScale()` and `divide()` operations

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result value of the addition operation of sum back to the variable sum

```
for (int a = 0; a < heights.length; a++)
    {
        sum = sum + heights[a];
        System.out.println("Height[" + a + "] = " + heights[a]);
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }
```